# Home networking - hopefully a simple solution - Trying to futureproof now - Maxing Clients on a single network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Here is my setup..

```
Ubiquity Edge Router 4
Ubiquity USW Pro PoE Switch
2 Ubiquity U6 Pro AP's (1 upstairs and 1 down)
```

I know I technically have no need for this and I probably never will. With my current setup (as far as I can tell) I have a max concurrent client of 254.  I may not ever have the need for more in a home environment.  I am however constantly scaling up due to my Work at home and other tinkering interests.

I have three WiFi networks...

```
192.168.10/24 - Home
192.168.20/24 - Work (VLAN Sequestered)
192.168.30/24 - Guest (VLAN Sequestered)
```

I want my home network to be able to achieve any limit needed for connected clients.
From what I have read, I need to mess with the subnet mask.
What I have now is 255.255.255.0 and what I think I need is 255.255.0.0.  Will this grant me 65K clients?

Is this correct and what would be the recommendations of altering the hardware to accommodate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With my current setup (as far as I can tell) I have a max concurrent client of 254.

You have three /24's, so that's a total of 3×254 clients. (Well, 3×253 as you need one address for the gateway.)

> What I have now is 255.255.255.0 and what I think I need is 255.255.0.0. Will this grant me 65K clients?

Using a /16 will grant you 65k addresses in that subnet, yes, but don't forget that you have three of them and need *non-overlapping* ranges for each subnet. You can't just change all three VLANs to use a /16 netmask because that'd make all of them use the same 192.168.0.0/16 address range and therefore they would all overlap.

(The networks won't be 192.168.10.0/16 – the netmask directly defines where the range starts and ends, and with /16 it always starts at x.x.0.0 and ends at x.x.255.255.)

Since 192.168.0.0/16 is already the whole "private use" range (no, you can't use 192.169), this would require you to start using network numbers out of 10.0.0.0/8 or 172.16.0.0/12, and that's perfectly fine from a technical perspective but a bit of a mess aesthetically.

I'd suggest to either a) to settle on smaller subnets, such as /20 for a middle ground, or b) if you want /16 then go all in and renumber *all* subnets to 10.x.0.0/16's, for example. (They don't all have to be equal in size, as long as there are no overlaps.)

However, keep in mind that the number of *active* devices will always be much smaller than the number of possible addresses in /16 or even /20. For example, your Ethernet switches probably have a limit of 4k or 8k learned MAC addresses (total across all VLANs), your WiFi bridges probably have a limit of connected stations in the low hundreds (at which point they'll be seriously competing for airtime anyway), and the amount of broadcast packets can begin to get annoying at that point as well.

So while you won't have any negative impact from merely using /20 or /16 netmasks as long as the number of active devices stays low, at some point it'll be better to expand in the direction of **more subnets** in their own VLANs than more hosts per subnet.